# Excel data set formatting issues

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dataset, client

I have a client data set I am struggling to organise. I was previously helped on here with a question on how to split a cell with words that had been formatted with no space. This worked successfully for the names of clients but now my data is a little more tricky in regards to their job title and company name as the variables are so different for each cell.
For example;

```
Cell 1 - First Name
Cell 2 - Last Name
Cell 3 - ManagerCompanyName
or
Cell 3 - Principle ManagerCompany Name
```

My problem is with cell 3 and the spacing. I would like it to be as:
Cell 3 - Manager
Cell 4 - Company Name

Is there any way of doing this without manually adding the spaces?

The code for seperating first and last name was:

```
=SMALL(IFERROR(FIND({"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"},A2,2),""),1)
```

and then

```
=MID(F2, (G2), 60)
```

I presume it is similar, however the inconsistancy is making me struggle.

Thank you

Comment: This might be a bit too tricky for Excel since Excel itself would need to have some rule to execute and find out where a title stops and the company name starts. In other words, with your 1st example. Who/what tells Excel that the title is 'Manager' and not 'ManagerCompany'? Your current code just finds the 1st uppercase letter. Btw, I see you never replied to any of the answers in that previous question you talk about.

Comment: To further add to my point; if you have data like 'Principle ManagerCompany Name', it's clear that the title is **not** just up to the very first capital. Hence, how do you expect Excel to know where you want to 'split' the input. Your best bet here may be to create a list of all possible titles first and see which ones are found in your input.

Answer (score 0):

`=LEFT(A2,IFERROR(SMALL(FIND(CHAR(65+SEQUENCE(26,,0)),A2,2),1)-1,LEN(A2)))`
Can be used to get the first word up to the next capital.

`=IFERROR(MID(A2,SMALL(IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(65+SEQUENCE(26,,0)),A2,2),""),1),LEN(A2)),"")`
To get the remainder from the 2nd found capital.

You can replace the `CHAR(65+SEQUENCE())` part with the array you used if you don't have Office 365

Comment: This only works if the manager name contains 1 capital and the company name starts with a capital.